# How do I un-require a node module and release its memory in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have read a couple articles about deleting require.cache['path to module'] like this one:
http://blog.alexanderseville.com/post/31919659559/un-require-in-nodejs

but it hasn't been working for me. In my node file, I have these two lines:

> var fileToJsonParser = require('xls-to-json');
>       delete require.cache[require.resolve('xls-to-json')];

I am running on Windows and watching memory usage in task manager. Without those two lines, node.exe's memory usage is about 30 MB, but with as soon as I require 'xls-to-json', the memory usage jumps up to 120 MB even when I try to delete require.cache.

Comment: That library also requires xlsjs and csv etc. What about releasing those too?

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. What about putting this stuff in a separate file and running it via `child_process.fork()`? When the process ends, everything gets released automatically.

Answer (score 5):

As explained by Alex Seville, [here](http://blog.alexanderseville.com/post/31919659559/un-require-in-nodejs), the important thing to note here is that **you’re not referencing the module in the same manner that you included it**. For example, if we wanted to bring in Mocha and then un-require it, the following code would not work:

```
var path = "mocha";
var mocha = require(path);
if (require.cache[path]){
    // Never gets here:
    delete require.cache[path];
}
```

Instead you’ll find the path in the cache to be something like `/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js`. That’s one of the many reasons why using this technique in production is probably not a good idea.

That being said, it **can** be done.

Check a package named '[resolve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve)', which might help out. In your case, use resolve.sync:

```
var fileToJsonParser = require('xls-to-json');
var resolve = require('resolve');

var path = resolve.sync('xls-to-json');
console.log("Path to module found:", path);

if (require.cache[path]){
    delete require.cache[path];
}
```

I haven't tested the exact code, but I do expect it to work.
I hope this helps. :)